# Script to Update/download most recent iTunes podcast WITHOUT opening iTunes at all?

Tags: itunes, applescript, script, command-line

I have a couple favorite podcasts that I subscribe to in iTunes.

I'm using You Control (so I don't have to open iTunes to play my music).

I'm using Keyboard Maestro.

I've made a macro that runs when logging in or on system wake. The macro should contain a script (AppleScript, Bash/Zsh/Ruby/Python, whatever) that automatically updates / downloads the most recent available podcasts in my subscriptions, in faceless mode, i.e. in the background, WITHOUT opening iTunes at all.

Is this possible and are there any scripts that does this exact thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the iTunes uses a encrypted database you (almost) won't be able to do it (without opening iTunes).